# Find top right-most coordinate in a list of coordinates

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, multidimensional-array, coordinates, distance

Say I have a list of (x, y) coordinates. One such list is this:

```
coords = [(7, 37), (6, 38), (6, 37), (7, 38), (6, 39), (7, 39), (6, 40), (7, 40), (6, 41), (7, 41), (6, 42), (7, 42), (6, 43), (7, 43), (6, 44), (7, 44), (6, 45), (7, 45), (6, 46), (7, 46), (6, 47), (7, 47), (6, 48), (7, 48), (6, 49), (7, 49), (6, 50), (7, 50), (6, 51), (7, 51), (6, 52), (7, 52), (6, 53), (7, 53), (6, 54), (7, 54), (6, 55), (7, 55), (6, 56), (7, 56), (6, 57), (7, 57)]
```

Now say I want to find the **top right** most corner of the rectangle formed by these coordinates.

Initially, I thought I could do `max(zip(*coords)[0]), min(zip(*coords)[1])`. This will give me the greatest x value, and the greatest Y value. However, this point is not guaranteed to be in the list.

The bottom right can be found with `max(coords)`. Top left is found by `min(coords)`. But if I want to find top right, **what is the most efficient way to do this.**

I can iterate through the list, and for each value, calculate its distance from `max(zip(*coords)[0]), min(zip(*coords)[1])`. But performing a square root for every value is not very efficient with larger lists of points.

Is there a quick way to find the top right point in a large list?

Comment: Do you have a preference on one of the axes? If not, what if there's **no** top-left coordinate (that is, in the list)?

Comment: In what cases would there not be a top left? If there's more than one? Not sure what you mean by "do you have a preference on one of the axes".

Comment: `(0, 0)` and `(1,1)` in a regular coordinate system. Which is the top left one?

Comment: You either looking for the corner(s) of the smallest bounding rectangle - for which you already have a solution. Or the point that is the closest to the corner - for which again you already a solution.

Comment: They're both equally close to (0,1), either one is acceptable. There will likely always be one in my data sets.

Comment: Then I'm not sure what the queston is... you already have an efficient solution.

Comment: I want to find the point closest to the corner. My solution of calculating Pythagorean distance is inefficient in lists of 100 or more points

Comment: Well, you can eliminate some of the points (e.g.: both coordinates in the wrong direction compared to another point), but in the end for the rest you *have to* calculate the distance.

Comment: Also, now that you mentioned 100 as a "threshold" I'm not sure you have a performance problem at all... probably just sheer overengineering?

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll try this

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution, I hope it works for you:

```
top_right = max(coords, key=lambda x: (x[0], -x[1]))
```

Edit: I didn't see the question was formulated 5 years ago lol.